# Get the geometry from the lasso selection tool

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, add-in

I'm building an Add-in solution in ArcGIS 10 that contains a custom tool. I'd like to borrow the functionality of the lasso selection tool without reinventing the wheel. Is there a way to intercept the geometry of the lasso selection area from the mouse up event? I want to pass the geometry of the lasso area to a spatial filter.

I know how to get control of the lasso tool with the following code in my custom tool class:

```
private ITool m_SelectTool;
protected override void OnActivate()
        {         
            UID uid = new UID();
            uid.Value = "esriArcMapUI.SelectByLassoTool";
            ICommandItem commandItem = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(uid, false, false);
            ICommand command = commandItem.Command;
            m_SelectTool  = (ITool)command;            
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible (intercepting another tool's private data/events), but the good news is that reinventing the wheel is pretty easy when the inventor shows you how to do it.

See the [Custom selection extension Add-In Sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003w2000000), particularly the [`SelectByLineTool`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000969000000) class. You could tweak it to use a [`NewPolygonFeedback`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/NewPolygonFeedbackClass_Class/001w000003r0000000/) instead of a line feedback, and add points to it in OnMouseMove instead of OnMouseDown, and Stop the feedback in OnMouseDown instead of OnDoubleClick.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The example just needed the tweaks you mentioned and I had it up and running really quick.

Comment: Glad to help! Just a suggestion, but if you would put your solution down as another answer I would gladly upvote it (earning you reputation instead of me :) See also [this discussion](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/801/how-should-the-question-asker-post-the-eventual-solution-they-used-if-they-based) on meta. If you do I'll rollback your edit it so it's not duplicated.

Comment: Posted solution as a separate answer. The edit I made to your post can be rolled back. Thanks for pointing out that discussion, I wondered which was the best way to handle the answer.

Comment: Done! Also think vinayan's suggestion to accept the answer which led to the solution as a courtesy is sound :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code used in my solution based on modifying the Esri custom selection extension Add-in sample:

```
private bool m_isMouseDown = false;
private ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.INewPolygonFeedback m_polyFeedback;
private IActiveView m_focusMap;

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs arg) 
{
    IMxDocument mxDoc = ArcMap.Document;
    m_focusMap = mxDoc.FocusMap as IActiveView;
    IPoint point = m_focusMap.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(arg.X, arg.Y) as IPoint;

    if (m_polyFeedback == null)
    {
        m_polyFeedback = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.NewPolygonFeedback();
        m_polyFeedback.Display = m_focusMap.ScreenDisplay;
        m_polyFeedback.Start(point);
    }
    else
    {
        m_polyFeedback.AddPoint(point);
    }

    m_isMouseDown = true;

}
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs arg)
{
    if (!m_isMouseDown) return;

    IMxDocument mxDoc = ArcMap.Document;
    m_focusMap = mxDoc.FocusMap as IActiveView;
    IPoint point = m_focusMap.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(arg.X, arg.Y) as IPoint;

    if (m_polyFeedback == null)
    {
        m_polyFeedback = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.NewPolygonFeedback();
        m_polyFeedback.Display = m_focusMap.ScreenDisplay;
        m_polyFeedback.Start(point);
    }
    else
    {
        m_polyFeedback.AddPoint(point);
    }

}
protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs arg)
{

    if (!m_isMouseDown) return;

    IPolygon polygon = m_polyFeedback.Stop();

    //Do something with the polygon here

    m_isMouseDown = false;
    m_polyFeedback = null;
}
```

Comment: Hi Rich, why in my vb.net project I cannot make mouseup/down/move override?

Comment: In vb.net I think the syntax needs the "Overloads" keyword: example)  Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal arg As MouseEventArgs)  You should be able to find a vb example in the online help.