# vb.net ArcObjects is there a function the same as "Select Features by Polygon" of ArcMap's tool

Tags: arcobjects, polygon, arcgis-10.2, vb.net, select

I want to know whether there is a function provided by ArcObjects (vb.net) to realize the "Select Features by Polygon" on ArcMap (shown below).

I am using VS 2012 (vb.net) and ArcObjects 10.2.2.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select features by polygon using ArcObjects, you would typically use a spatial filter, which is very simple to implement. Here's an example in VB.NET, where pPolygon is your polygon object, and pLayer is the layer you wish to select features from:

```vb
' create the spatial filter
Dim pSpatialFilter As ISpatialFilter = New SpatialFilterClass()
pSpatialFilter.Geometry = pPolygon
pSpatialFilter.GeometryField = pLayer.FeatureClass.ShapeFieldName
pSpatialFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelContains

' select features
Dim pFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection
pFeatureSelection = pLayer
pFeatureSelection.SelectFeatures(pSpatialFilter, esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultAdd, False)
```

If you want to draw the polygon yourself using ArcObjects, then that's a bit of extra work. There are sample functions available to draw a polygon with mouse clicks (just google it), and then use that polygon object as your spatial filter input.

Comment: Hi lcoursey, I have followed the sample code to draw a polygon on map, but the start point always on the top of the map, is there is a way to allow user start drawings at any point as required ( the same as "Select Features by Polygon" tool? thanks.

Comment: @littleleaf What sample code are you using? Can you send me a link?

Comment: Hi lcoursey , thanks for the concern, the sample code I use from the following link: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000238000000

Comment: I posted some code for how to do something similar to what you're attempting here. Scroll to the last answer for the complete code.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26067/get-the-geometry-from-the-lasso-selection-tool

Comment: Thank you Rich, but unfortunately I failed to make it work after I convert your code to vb.net. even don't know how to call the code on OnMouseDown, Move and Up. I can't put Overrides on them.